# Lazy loading of LOBs using Hibernate (was : Bad encoding on Resteasy picture upload)

Tags: encoding, ejb, resteasy

I'm trying to upload files to a web service using curl, then save those files in a database. It's working well so far for text files, but pictures are corrupted.

So let's say I'm uploading the file logo.png using curl :

`curl -T D:\logo.png http://127.0.0.1:8080/my-web-service/resteasy/document/metadata?id=logo"&"contentType=IMAGE"&"httpType=image"/"png`

My webservice consumes the data like this:

```
@Path("metadata")
@PUT
public void putDocument(
    @QueryParam("id") String docId,
    @DefaultValue("GENERIC_CONTENT") @QueryParam("contentType") String contentType,
    @DefaultValue("text/html") @QueryParam("httpType") String httpType,
    byte[] docContent) {
Document doc = new Document();
doc.setDocumentId(docId);
doc.setContentType(new RefContentType(ContentType.valueOf(contentType)));
doc.setHttpContentType(httpType);
doc.setContent(docContent);
doc = getDAO().save(doc);
LOG.info("Document saved successfully id : " + doc.getId());
```

So my best guess is that the setContent method doesn't work well with a byte array containing something other than plain text. How can I know if curl is messing the upload or if it's my ejb that reads the array badly?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the uploading worked fine. i could confirm this by saving the array on my disk as an image file using Java `BufferedImage` class.

The problem lies in Hibernate's annotations.

My byte array was saved in an Oracle blob using this Java variable:

```
@Column(name="CONTENT")
@Lob //@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
byte[] content= null;
```

The `@Lob` and `@Basic` annotations are not working properly together. For more explanation on this see this question : [Spring, Hibernate, Blob lazy loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605477/spring-hibernate-blob-lazy-loading)