# Hibernate Default Lob Lazy/Eager

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading, eager

When hibernate loads an object containing a field annotated with @Lob will this field be loaded eagerly or lazily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is loaded lazily. 
Read [this](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/ANN-418) jira ticket and comment for this by Emmanuel Bernard. 
And also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605477/spring-hibernate-blob-lazy-loading)

Comment: Only caveat is that you need bytecode instrumentation enabled otherwise it will be eagerly loaded.