# Spring Blob lazy loading

Tags: hibernate, blob, fetch, lazy-evaluation

Does anyone know if the hibernate bug in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605477/spring-hibernate-blob-lazy-loading) has been fixed yet

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 0):

For lazy loading of fields/columns (as opposed to relationships) Hibernate needs bytecode instrumentation. Which works fine, but it's not quite "out of the box". Although this may be annoying, it is not necessarily a bug. Then there are some workarounds that seem not the intended way, but would be fine, if only they worked, which isn't the case for me. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what you mean when you say Hibernate needs bytecode instrumentation. Could you elaborate? Could you point me to and example or further documentation of this? - Thanks