# Why the fetch=FetchType.LAZY directive don't work when I retrieve an object using Hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

I am pretty new in JPA and Hibernate and I have the following problem.

Into a **Spring MVC** project I have this **Tid001Anagpartecipa** model class that map the fields on the **TID001_ANAGPARTECIPA** table defined on the database:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TID001_ANAGPARTECIPA")
@NamedQuery(name="Tid001Anagpartecipa.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM Tid001Anagpartecipa t")
public class Tid001Anagpartecipa implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="PRG_PAR")
    private Integer prgPar;

    ................................................................
    ................................................................
    ................................................................

    @Lob @Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @Column(name="OGG_DOC_ALL")
    private byte[] oggDocAll;
    
    
    @Lob @Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @Column(name="OGG_DOC_DEL_ALL")
    private byte[] oggDocDelAll;

    ................................................................
    ................................................................
    GETTER & SETTER METHODS
    ................................................................
    ................................................................
}
```

As you can see on this table there are 2 **BLOB** fields annoted with the **@Lob** annotation, these fields contain 2 files stored on the DB.

In this class is also declared this **named query** that retrieve all the **Tid001Anagpartecipa** object stored as record of the **TID001_ANAGPARTECIPA** table:

As you can see in the previous code snipper the **@Lob** fields it used the **lazy** strategy (by **@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)**). So I expected that when I retrieve a **Tid001Anagpartecipa** object these 2 **@Lob** fields are not initizialized.

Into a controller method I perform this operation that retrieve the **Tid001Anagpartecipa** object:

```
Tid001Anagpartecipa anagrafica = getAnagraficaPartecipante(model);
List<Tid002Candidatura> listaCandidatureDB = anagrafica.getTid002Candidaturas();
```

The object is correctly retrieve but the problem is that the previous 2 **@Lob** fields are inizialized and I want that these fields are not inizialized (infact I used the **@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)** directive).

Why are these fields retrieved? What am I missing? How can I say to Hibernate to not retrieve these **@Lob** fields when the **Tid001Anagpartecipa** is retrieved?

Answer (score 1):

Section 11.1.6 of the JPA spec notes with regard to the @Basic annotation:

> The LAZY strategy is a hint to the persistence provider runtime that
>   data should be fetched lazily when it is first accessed. The
>   implementation is permitted to eagerly fetch data for which the LAZY
>   strategy hint has been specified.

Hibernate **does** support lazy loading of simple properties but requires byte code enhancement to do so:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties

And without this:

> If your persistent classes are not enhanced, Hibernate will ignore
>   lazy property settings and return to immediate fetching.

Comment: Nothing. You need to change your build process to enhance the classes. If using maven and hibernate >=4.2.8 then you should just be able to the relevant plugin to you pom.xml. See the section 'hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin' here https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-bytecode-enhancement

Answer (score 0):

What does lazy mean? It means things are loaded on demand. There are two ways to make it happen: by using proxies (intercept the call in the proxy and load the thing) or by bytecode enhancement (modify the bytecode of the entity class so that lazy access is intercepted).

Since you cannot make a proxy for `byte[]`, the second approach is the only eligible one.

However, you could extract the lob to a separate lazily-loaded entity, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31356048/4754790).