# How does Hibernate handle Blob?

Tags: java, hibernate

I've got a table with the following structure:

```
int id | blob file_to_store | int version
```

This is how my domain works:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FileToStore")
public class FileToStore{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int Id;

    @Column(name = "version")
    private int version;

    @Column(name = "file_to_store")
    @Lob
    private Blob file;

    //gets and sets
}
```

Sometimes I just need a file version. Like this :

```
FileToStore fileToStore=FileToStoreService.get(id);
return fileToStore.getVersion();
```

Is that going to work fast or I have to write another SQL query to take version field only to avoid loading file? [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html) says

> Blob object contains a logical pointer to the SQL BLOB data rather
>   than the data itself

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question boils down to wether Hibernate fetches lobs lazily.
And based on discussion here [Spring, Hibernate, Blob lazy loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605477/spring-hibernate-blob-lazy-loading?rq=1) I would advise to test it on your evnironment.